# Why do I feel as if Allah doesn’t listen to me

Tags: quran, hadith, allah, dua, forgiveness

I have made countless duas and but none get accepted. At first it was of grades then to get accepted into a uni. After I didn’t get accepted I researched on duas and figured it may have not been best for me. Then I made dua to pass in my uni and that didn’t happen I got offered another chance and didn’t pass that as well after so much dua and I didn’t just make dua I also tried and studied. I pray and ask for constant forgiveness but now I feel helpless I don’t know what I’m doing wrong or why nothing works out for me even if I have so much hope I cry to Allah but I don’t feel as if I am being heard why?

Answer (score 2):

This is a very real and heartfelt question. I hope I'm able to offer you some feedback that answers your question sufficiently AND soothes your aching heart. Here goes....

Firstly, let me assure you that Allah definitely listens and hears your duas.

"When My servants ask you concerning Me, I am indeed close.I LISTEN TO THE DUA OF EVERY SUPPLICANT WHEN HE CALLS ON ME...." Surat-al-Baqara, ayat 186 (2:186)

So, yes, He's listening to your duas. The question is, "why won't Allah give you what you want?" That's really what's vexing you,so that is what I will address.

Everyone knows of the Sunnah (or well-known practices) of the Messenger of Allah (SAWS), but a lot of times we forget that Allah also has a Sunnah, or way of doing things, that He does not deviate from.

"The Sunnah of Allah among those who lived aforetime. No change will you find in the Sunnah of Allah." Surat-al-Ahzab, ayat 62 (33:62)

"Then no change will you find in Allah's Sunnah. No turning off will you find in Allah's Sunnah." Surat-al-Fatir, ayat 43 (35:43)

Now, with regard to our duas, Allah's Sunnah is that 1) we ask Him for what we want; and then 2) we strive RELENTLESSLY in pursuit of what we want.

"Man can have nothing but what he strives for, and the fruit of his striving will soon come in sight." Surat-an-Najm,ayah 39-40 (53:39-40)

Dear brother (or sister) it is Allah Who feeds the birds, BUT HE DOES NOT PUT THE FOOD IN THEIR NESTS. No, they have to get up everyday and go looking for something to eat. Likewise, we are obliged to GO GET IT --WHATEVER IT IS WE DESIRE.

Now, yes, you said you did try. You studied. You worked hard. All of that. Still you were unsuccessful in your endeavors. Okay, listen to me now....

Thomas Edison is the man who invented the lightbulb. It is said that he FAILED in trying to make his invention work something like 1,000 times, but eventually he got it to work. When asked why he refused to give up after over 900 failed attempts to make his invention work, he said, "because I knew I only had to get it right once."

That is the kind of tenacity and determination you have to have when pursuing your goals and aspirations. The Arabic word for it is 'AZM = resolve, determination, firmness of purpose.

To put it simply, you have to try. If you fail, then try again. Then try again. Then step back, re-think and revise your strategy, AND THEN TRY AGAIN. Keep trying. Do not give up. Keep trying, striving, struggling towards your goals until you get what you want, OR UNTIL IT IS REVEALED THAT IT'S NOT MEANT FOR YOU TO HAVE WHAT YOU WANT.

The Qada of Allah is always a factor, even though I don't personally concern myself with it when I'm in pursuit of my own goals. Let me explain why.

Qada is what has been written for you in the Decree of Allah.Your money, your possessions, your good times, and your rough times, all of that has already been measured out for you. I accept that as true. But it is also true that NONE OF US KNOWS WHAT HAS BEEN WRITTEN IN THE DECREE OF ALLAH FOR US. We just don't. And I don't take failures (not even repeated failures) as some kind mystic message from Allah that He doesn't want me to have the object of my desire. I see failures as feedback from my efforts that tells me that I just used the wrong method to do whatever I'm trying to do.

That's how I see it, and it works for me. There have been many times when I've tried to get something done and I failed. Then I tried and tried and tried, and finally I succeeded. Alhamdulillah!

Allah is Al-Ghani (Rich) and Al-Kareem (Generous). He is the Ultimate Cause behind all effects in this Dunya. When we try something and it works for us, it is Allah Who made it work. He granted our efforts EFFICACY. THIS IS THE TRUTH.

This world operates according to laws and principles. Once you understand the laws that govern a thing you can make that thing happen anytime you want.

For example, the three elements of fire is fuel, heat, and and oxygen. If you want fire, bring these three things together. If you want to destroy fire then take one of them away. This is law.

Likewise, success is also governed by laws. Learn them, and then use them to your advantage.

I advise you to find someone who has done what you desire to do, and then ask them exactly what they did to attain the goal. They can give you a lot of good insights that you may not even be aware of. It's possible that you're overlooking something or leaving our a necessary ingredient for success in your endeavors. At any rate, modeling successful people is an excellent way to pursue your own success. The Messenger of Allah is a model for us to follow to be successful on the Day of Judgment. You need a role model for getting into the University. Try it. It can't hurt.

In closing, I leave you with this thought:

Allah answers our duas with His Guidance, His Grace, and His Blessings.

His Guidance (al-hudaa) is His telling us what we should or shouldn't do, or sending someone to us with the knowledge
we may be in need of.

His Grace (an-ni'mat) is sending us the people and things we need in our lives, and His removing of obstacles that impede our progress.

His Blessings (al-barakat) is the granting of EFFICACY to our efforts so that they bear the fruit that we desire.

Guidance, Grace, and Blessings are all different expressions of His Compassion (RAH'MAT) upon us. Never EVER give up hope for the RAH'MAT of your Lord, for Allah is Ar-Rah'maan (Most Gracious) and Ar-Raheem (Most Merciful).

Praise be to Allah, the Lord of all the world's!

As'salaamu alaykum.

Answer (score 1):

Bismillahir Rahmanir Rahim. Alhamdulillahi rabbil-'alamin. Was-Salatu was-Salam 'ala Sayyidina wa Azimina, Wa Habibi Qulubina wa Shafii Nufusina, Abul Qasim Muhammad. Wa 'ala Ahli Bayti tayyibina tahireen.

---

### Why do I feel as if Allah doesn’t listen to me

`I have made countless duas and but none get accepted.`

`I cry to Allah but I don’t feel as if I am being heard why?`

Feeling as if Allah does not hear is a sign of Kufr (Disbelief). And one who believes that Allah does not hear is a Kafeer (Disbeliever).

Allah has given clear signs in Quran that He hears His servants. Statements like ***"Allah hears"*** or ***"Allah is All-Hearing"*** or ***"He is Hearing"*** and alike, all together, mentioned in the scripture at least 8 times (according to my own counting on search page at legacy.quran.com). The **"[All-Hearing](https://99names.app/26)"**, Arabic ٱلْسَّمِيعُ, is one of the 99 attributes of Allah. Thus, one who believes that Allah does not hear is rejecting this attribute of Allah and the verses of Qur'an.

This problem, feeling as if Allah doesn’t hear, has been given answer in Quranic verse 10:100

> And it is not for a soul [i.e., anyone] to believe except by
> permission of Allāh, and He will place **defilement (Arabic الرجس -
> uncleanness)** upon those who will not use reason [original Arabic is
> **"La Ya'Qiloon"** - do not use A'ql (intellect)].
>
> [Quran 10:100](https://quran.com/10/100)

Imam Jafar As-Sadiq explains the defilement

> (It has been narrated) from Abu Abdullah (asws) having said: ‘The
> uncleanness (الرجس– ) **it is the doubt**. By Allah (azwj), we (asws)
> do not doubt regarding our (asws) Lord (azwj), ever’.
>
> [TafseerHub-e-Ali, page 58](https://hubeali.com/books/English-Books/TafseerHub-e-Ali/CH10_SuraYunus_Verses59-109.pdf)

So we have the story of a person who made Dua to Allah, asking certain things to happen, but it didn't happen and the person, as a result, is having doubts - feeling as if Allah doesn't hear him. The verse 10:100 says that doubts are put by Allah if servant does not use A'ql (intellect).

What does it mean? It means the protagonist of our story should use his A'ql (intellect), reason, understand why what happened happened, in order to avoid doubts which eventually will lead to Kufr. It means if one makes a conclusion without pondering over the event he will make a mistake.

We need to consider a number of  questions in order to understand and ponder the event then make best, correct conclusons. For instance, "What is Dua?", "How one makes Dua?", "What are the prerequisites for making dua?", "What should we ask in Dua?", "When does Allah accept Dua?", "How Allah responds to Dua?", "What to do after receiving response to Dua?", "What to do if Dua is not accepted?", "What to do if Dua is not responded?", and so on and so forth.

One may think what's the importance of having answers to these questions.

Let's consider the first question "What is Dua?", for example. Most people have wrong understanding of this Islamic concept and what's in their mind is that making Dua is similar to making an online order to a delivery service to get pizza, thus, if one makes Dua to Allah then that's it (Bob's your uncle), what you asked magically gets done. And what people do is that, based on this false incorrect understanding, they put too much hope to Duas they make, expecting surprising phenomenal outcomes, and eventually get frustrated when they end up with not getting what they expected.

Or let's consider the question "What should we ask in Dua?". This is one of the fateful questions that, unfortunately, most people do not know the answer to and possess relevant knowledge. Quran 2 says

> 200.And among the people is he who says, "Our Lord, give us in this world," and he will have in the Hereafter no share.
>
> [Quran 2:200](https://quran.com/2/200)

So a person who asks Allah to give in this world is making the biggest mistake, price for which will be payed in hereafter and this is what most of the people do we see in everyday life. So to having answer to the question "What should we ask in Dua?" depends our fate in eternal life in Hereafter. And the next verses, 201-202, explains what is correct to ask in duas we make.

> 201.But among them is he who says, "Our Lord, give us in this world [that which is] good and in the Hereafter [that which is] good and
> protect us from the punishment of the Fire." 202.Those will have a
> share of what they have earned, and Allāh is swift in account.
>
> [2:201-202](https://quran.com/2/201-202)

So based on these verses it is possible that Allah didn't answer the Dua out of His mercy as He declares Himself mercy and didn't want the servant to be deprived from share in Hereafter.

Each the rest of the questions listed above, regarding the concept of Dua , should be considered and thoroughly studied in similar way and I will leave it as a homework to the OP.